# two joins between two instances of two tables

Tags: select, join, nested

I have two instances of TABLE1 called TABLE A & TABLE C. I also have two instances of TABLE2 called TABLE B & TABLE D.

I need to join A and B as GROUP1
I need to join C and D as GROUP2

all within the same query, so I can apply a WHERE clause to add conditions to find matches between GROUP1 & GROUP2.

Not sure of the best way to go about this. Two nested SELECT statements? INNER JOIN? Here is what I have so far:

SELECT GROUP1.EMPLID, GROUP1.EMPL_STATUS, GROUP1.BANK_CD, GROUP1.ACCOUNT_NUM, GROUP2.EMPLID, GROUP2.EMPL_STATUS, GROUP2.BANK_CD, GROUP2.ACCOUNT_NUM 
FROM (

(SELECT * FROM
          (PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A1, PS_CU_PAF B1
           WHERE A1.EMPLID = B1.EMPLID
           AND B1.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P')
           AS GROUP1))

(SELECT * FROM
          (PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB C1, PS_CU_PAF D1
           WHERE C1.EMPLID = D1.EMPLID
           AND D1.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P')
           AS GROUP2))

WHERE GROUP1.EMPLID != GROUP2.EMPLID
  AND GROUP1.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P')
  AND GROUP2.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P')
  AND GROUP1.BANK_CD = GROUP2.BANK_CD
  AND GROUP1.ACCOUNT_NUM = GROUP2.ACCOUNT_NUM
)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going about it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLID "EMP1_ID", B.EMPL_STATUS "EMP1_STATUS", A.BANK_CD "EMP1_BANK", A.ACCOUNT_NUM "EMP1_ACCT", 
            C.EMPLID "EMP2_ID", D.EMPL_STATUS "EMP2_STATUS", C.BANK_CD "EMP2_BANK", C.ACCOUNT_NUM "EMP2_ACCT"

  FROM PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A, PS_CU_PAF B, PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB C, PS_CU_PAF D

  WHERE A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
    AND C.EMPLID = D.EMPLID
    AND A.EMPLID != C.EMPLID
    AND B.JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
    AND D.JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
    AND B.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P')
    AND D.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P')
    AND A.BANK_CD = C.BANK_CD
    AND A.ACCOUNT_NUM = C.ACCOUNT_NUM
    AND C.ACCOUNT_NUM != ' '

    AND A.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A_ED
                   WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID)

    AND C.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB C_ED
                   WHERE C.EMPLID = C_ED.EMPLID)

ORDER BY 4, 1
```